# Testing & Deploy Azure Data Projects

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

As Data Engineer and Azure developer I like to automate testing and deployments on the cloud. Currently I'm working with several azure resources such as Azure Data Factory, Azure Data Lake Storage, Azure Data Lake Analytics, SQL Server and PowerBI.

Doing some research I've found a bunch of articles in the Microsoft site related to DevOps in Data Science Team: [Team Data Science Process for Developer Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/team-data-science-process/team-data-science-process-for-devops)

Apart from that I didn't find anything interesting. I would like to find a way to accelerate the process to deploy code and assuring quality at the same time. In the end, we want to move our processes into a DevOps ecosystem.

Someone could recommend a lecture o something where I can start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Azure Data Lake Tools team is working on CI/CD features. There may be a blog post on our [Azure Data Lake Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredatalake/) that is of interest. Otherwise, I suggest to wait or contact a PM on that team to provide requirements and feedback.